# Get only value for select in Angular

Tags: angularjs, select

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I want the **value** of the month selector (eg. 2). What I'm getting is

```
{val: 2, name: 'Feb'}
```

Here is my view with the month selector:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Expiry Month</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select ng-model="cartModalVm.creditCard.CardExpiryMonth"
                ng-options="month.name for month in cartModalVm.months track by month.val"
                name="cardExpiryMonth"
                class="form-control input-inline input-medium"
                required>
            <option value="">Month</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how they're set in my controller:

```
vm.months = [
    { val: 1, name: 'January' },
    { val: 2, name: 'February' },
    { val: 3, name: 'March' },
    { val: 4, name: 'April' },
    { val: 5, name: 'May' },
    { val: 6, name: 'June' },
    { val: 7, name: 'July' },
    { val: 8, name: 'August' },
    { val: 9, name: 'September' },
    { val: 10, name: 'October' },
    { val: 11, name: 'November' },
    { val: 12, name: 'December' }
```

I guess I don't really need **val** property in my object, I can just use $index, but that won't solve the problem. What do I point the model at to simply get '2'?

This works for now, but it sucks:

```
vm.creditCard.CardExpiryMonth = vm.creditCard.CardExpiryMonth.val;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `ngOptions` to:

```
ng-options="month.val as month.name for month in cartModalVm.months"
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  function MainCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.months = [
      { val: 1, name: 'January' },
      { val: 2, name: 'February' },
      { val: 3, name: 'March' },
      { val: 4, name: 'April' },
      { val: 5, name: 'May' },
      { val: 6, name: 'June' },
      { val: 7, name: 'July' },
      { val: 8, name: 'August' },
      { val: 9, name: 'September' },
      { val: 10, name: 'October' },
      { val: 11, name: 'November' },
      { val: 12, name: 'December' } 
    ];
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as cartModalVm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Expiry Month</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <select ng-model="cartModalVm.creditCard.CardExpiryMonth" ng-options="month.val as month.name for month in cartModalVm.months" name="cardExpiryMonth" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" required>
        <option value label="Month" hidden></option>
      </select>
      <hr>
      Selected month: <pre ng-bind="cartModalVm.creditCard.CardExpiryMonth"></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```